# Time difference in seconds from numpy.timedelta64

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

How to get time difference in seconds from numpy.timedelta64 variable?

```
time1 = '2012-10-05 04:45:18'
time2 = '2012-10-05 04:44:13'
dt = np.datetime64(time1) - np.datetime64(time2)
print dt

0:01:05
```

I'd like to convert `dt` to number (int or float) representing time difference in seconds.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can access it through the "wrapped" datetime item:

```
>>> dt.item().total_seconds()
65.0
```

*Explanation*: here `dt` is an [array scalar](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) in `numpy`, which is a zero rank array or 0-dimensional array.  So you will find the `dt` here also has all the methods an ndarray possesses, and you can do for example `dt.astype('float')`.  But it wraps a python object, in this case a `datetime.timedelta` object.

To get the original scalar you can use `dt.item()`. To index the array scalar you can use the somewhat bizarre syntax of getitem using an empty tuple:

```
>>> dt[()]
array(datetime.timedelta(0, 65), dtype='timedelta64[s]')
```

This should work in all versions of numpy, but if you are using numpy v1.7+ it may be better to use the newer numpy datetime API directly as explained in the answer from [J.F. Sebastien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921192/674039) here.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you please explain why dt.seconds doesn't work?

Comment: It's `datetime.timedelta` that has an attribute named like that, not a `numpy.timedelta64`.  I don't know why numpy implemented it like that though, maybe someone else can answer ..

Comment: Worth noting: if the `timedelta64` object is of dtype `timedelta64[ns]` this will not work, you need to cast to `timedelta64[s]` first (i.e. `dt.astype('timedelta64[s]').item().total_seconds()`). I've been bitten by this so many times

Answer (score 102):

To get number of seconds from `numpy.timedelta64()` object using [`numpy` 1.7 experimental datetime API](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

```
seconds = dt / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

Comment: We maybe using different versions?  I have `TypeError: function takes at most 1 argument (2 given)` when trying `np.timedelta64(1, 's')`

Comment: @wim: yes. [1.6 and 1.7 API differ](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic).

Comment: For a pandas series, use `series.apply(lambda x: x / timedelta64(1, 's'))` (**NumPy 1.7.1**, **pandas 0.12.0**)

Comment: another way of applying the same logic to a series: `np.divide(mySeries, np.timedelta64(1, 's'))` is about 70 times faster than the apply method above

Comment: I get `TypeError: ufunc divide cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[us]') and dtype('<m8[s]')`

Comment: @JasonS do you understand the difference between datetime64 and timedelta64 (the difference, look at the code in the question: dt is timedelta64, not datetime64)

Answer (score 8):

You can simply cast the value to the desired time unit using np.astype, as shown in the example:

```
timedelta = np.datetime64('2011-07-18')-np.datetime64('2011-07-16')
seconds = timedelta.astype('timedelta64[s]').astype(np.int32)
hours = timedelta.astype('timedelta64[h]').astype(np.int32)
```

Comment: `timedelta.astype('timedelta64[s]')` seems to truncate millisecond precision to me 


``
[147] elapsed_time.iloc[0]
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00.005322600')
[148] elapsed_time.iloc[0]/ np.timedelta64(1, 's')
0.0053226
[149] elapsed_time.astype('timedelta64[s]').astype(np.float64).iloc[0]
0.0
``

Comment: Nice - missed the intermediate type conversion