# Create a series of days between timestamps - DUPLICATE LINK ABOVE DOESN'T SOLVE

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have two date features of type datetime.   I'd like to express the difference between them in days cast as type int.   How do I accomplish this:

```
In[]
print lcd.time_to_default
print lcd.issue_date

lcd['time_to_default']=(lcd.last_pymnt_date - lcd.issue_date)

lcd.time_to_default.head()

Out[92]:
datetime64[ns]
datetime64[ns]

0   1127 days
1    487 days
2    913 days
3   1127 days
4   1217 days
Name: time_to_default, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I want to cast this series as an int, not timedelta64.

Addendum:  I can't cast this as ".days" as the link above which supposes a duplicate, suggests.

In[]
   lcd.time_to_default.days

Returns:
   Out[]
   'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract the two datetime variables. That yields timedelta type.

Eg:

```
In [2]: datetime.datetime.now()
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 2, 0, 30, 49, 548657)

In [3]: yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

In [4]: datetime.datetime.now() -  yesterday
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(1, 17, 32459)

In [5]: diff = (datetime.datetime.now() -  yesterday)

In [6]: diff.days
Out[6]: 1
```

Comment: Yes, but the dtype is time delta64.    How can I cast to int?

Comment: I dont see a `delta64` type for any variable here (unless its a short form i dont know)

Comment: @HiteshDharamdasani, that is because it is more than likely a pandas Series

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date1 = datetime(2015,6,2)
>>> date2 = datetime(2015,5,2)
>>> diff = date1 - date2
>>> print (diff.days)
31
```

Comment: But I can't cast the series as .days.   The line:                  lcd['time_to_default']= (lcd.last_pymnt_date - lcd.issue_date).days                   Returns the error:                                                                                   'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

Comment: can you help by looking at my comment above?

Answer (score 0):

To get integer number of days from a series of `timedelta64[ns]`, you could try (not tested):

```
result = np.divide(lcd.time_to_default, np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
```

See [Time difference in seconds from numpy.timedelta64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14920903/4279) and [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13703720/4279).