# Compare two datetime objects to see if they are at most 2 minutes apart

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of DateTime objects, and I want to compare if any two of them has the same Hour and Minutes or at most 2 minutes apart. I compare them by using the `itertools.combinations( data, 2 )`. But I am stuck in the comparison part. I am not sure how to compare 2 minutes or more because if one timestamp is 11:58 two minutes more will be 12:00, which means I can add 2 to 11:58 as it will go to 11:60 instead of 12:00.

I converted the dateTime objects to string with this

```
dt1 = int((acqList[a].timestamp).time().strftime('%H%M'))
dt2 = int((acqList[b].timestamp).time().strftime('%H%M'))
```

Then, I did this

```
if dt1 == dt2 or dt1+1 == dt2 or dt2+1 == dt1 or dt1-1 == dt2 or dt2-1 == dt1:
```

but this will lead to the concern of 1160 and did not include at most 2 minutes difference

example of the dateTime object List:

```
2019-10-01 15:37:11+00:00
2019-10-01 15:37:09+00:00
2019-10-01 16:09:06+00:00
2019-10-01 15:24:55+00:00
2019-10-01 16:36:56+00:00
2019-10-01 10:08:39+00:00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if two datetimes are within a certain range of each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635426/how-to-check-if-two-datetimes-are-within-a-certain-range-of-each-other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not pass to string, numeric values are easier to compare.

From two `datetime` object you can compare them, in each way using this method

```
d1 = datetime.now()
d2 = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=2)

if fabs((d1 - d2).total_seconds()) <= 120:
    print("diff lower than 2m")
```

The following would fit but in only one way :

```
if (d1 - d2) <= timedelta(minutes=2):
    print("diff lower than 2m")
```

---

To find if a list of datetime are in a 2-min interval, check that every combination is lower than 2min

```
values = [datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=randint(0, 2)) for i in range(20)]
combi = combinations(values, 2)
if all([fabs((d1 - d2).total_seconds()) <= 120 for d1, d2 in combi]):
    print("All values fit in a 2-min interval")
```

Comment: Gotcha. So do I still need to convert the datetime object into string or int?

Comment: @xd3262nd into none of them, You want every value to be in a 2-min interval ?

Comment: yea. I want to check if they are in 2-min interval. I think I get it now. Thanks so much for your help! Learning new things now

Comment: Do you mind to explain this code to me? ```if all([fabs((d1 - d2).total_seconds()) <= 120 for d1, d2 in combi]):
    print("All values fit in a 2-min interval")``` I ran it but it does not show any print statement at all

Comment: @xd3262nd If for all combination of values, the difference between the 2 is lower than 2min, you'll the print. With the previous line I build a list of datetime that between now, and 2min before now, so ALL are in the same 2-3min intervall and the condition will be true

Comment: right but it does not show any print statement on my end when I'm trying to run your example code above

Comment: @xd3262nd Did you increase the size of the list ? use randint(0, 1), maybe your list tak to much time to build, and one value is out of the interval

Comment: Yea, it works now I changed that and the range to (10). Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, sorry so I am facing some issues and thinking I might change my approach to get the least difference of ```fabs(d2-d1)``` instead of ```if fabs((d1 - d2).total_seconds()) <= 120:``` but I am not sure how I can approach that

Comment: @xd3262nd you need to keep total_seconds(), you can't do absolute of timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Using datetime objects, you can calculate the difference directly substracting the value from the shifted column:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(7), columns = ['date'], 
>>>data=['2012-03-16 23:50:00',
'2012-03-16 23:56:00',
'2012-03-17 00:08:00',
'2012-03-17 00:10:00',
'2012-03-17 00:12:00',
'2012-03-17 00:20:00',
'2012-03-20 00:43:00'])
>>>df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


>>>df['delta'] = (df['date']-df['date'].shift()).fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0))

    date    delta
0   2012-03-16 23:50:00 0 days 00:00:00
1   2012-03-16 23:56:00 0 days 00:06:00
2   2012-03-17 00:08:00 0 days 00:12:00
3   2012-03-17 00:10:00 0 days 00:02:00
4   2012-03-17 00:12:00 0 days 00:02:00
5   2012-03-17 00:20:00 0 days 00:08:00
6   2012-03-20 00:43:00 3 days 00:23:00
```