# Convert datetime64 to seconds

Tags: python, time, datetime64

I subtracted two datetime64 columns and got a column of results such as '00:20:32' and '00:08:21.'
How do I then convert those  datetime64 values to seconds?

Comment: Please add more information regarding the question. A minimum reprodiclbe example and and expected output would be nice!

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920903/time-difference-in-seconds-from-numpy-timedelta64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time difference in seconds from numpy.timedelta64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920903/time-difference-in-seconds-from-numpy-timedelta64) ... another, maybe better: [Convert timedelta64 column to seconds in Python Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456825/convert-timedelta64ns-column-to-seconds-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head (and with the poor information in the question), if there's a column that contains hours, minutes and seconds, which I will call "time" I would create the following column in the dataframe:

```
df['full_seconds'] = df['time'].dt.seconds
```

Or use a simple calculus summing hours, minutes and seconds:

```
df['full_seconds'] = df['time'].dt.hour * 3600 + df['time'].dt.minute * 60 + df['time'].dt.second
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you paste the code to make to question more precise ?

Generally you can do that using [NumPy timedelta64](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

`np.timedelta64( timedate1 - timedate2 ,'s')`